# How do I use MVVM with EF 6 database first?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, entity-framework-6

I have a WPF project which reads Database entries. I built the model with EF 6 from the database.

Now I am a little bit confused how to apply the MVVM Pattern.

This is the **model class** generated from EF 6:

```
public partial class Folder
    {
        public string FolderPath { get; set; }
        public string UserGroup { get; set; }
        public string Permission { get; set; }
        public string AccessControllType { get; set; }
        public string IsInherited { get; set; }
        public int FolderId { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the **MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ADAccessRightsEntities _context = new ADAccessRightsEntities();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource folderViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("folderViewSource")));
        

        folderViewSource.Source = _context.Folders.ToList();

    }

    protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosing(e);
            this._context.Dispose();
        }
}
```

**This is my xaml code:**

```
    <Window x:Class="PermissoinViewer.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PermissoinViewer"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
        <Window.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="folderViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Folder}, CreateList=True}"/>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="userGroupViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:UserGroup}, CreateList=True}"/>
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource folderViewSource}">
            <DataGrid x:Name="folderDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,10,313,209" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="accessControllTypeColumn" Binding="{Binding AccessControllType}" Header="Access Controll Type" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="folderIdColumn" Binding="{Binding FolderId}" Header="Folder Id" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="folderPathColumn" Binding="{Binding FolderPath}" Header="Folder Path" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="isInheritedColumn" Binding="{Binding IsInherited}" Header="Is Inherited" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="permissionColumn" Binding="{Binding Permission}" Header="Permission" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="userGroupColumn" Binding="{Binding UserGroup}" Header="User Group" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**How do I include a VM class now?**

**Edit1:**
I created a FolderVM class.

```
class FolderVM : AViewModel
{
    private Folder folder;

    public FolderVM(Folder folder)
    {
        this.folder = folder;
    }

    public string FolderPath
    {
        get => folder.FolderPath;
        set
        {
            folder.FolderPath = value;
            CallPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string UserGroup
    {
        get => folder.UserGroup;
        set
        {
            folder.UserGroup = value;
            CallPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string Permission
    {
        get => folder.Permission;
        set
        {
            folder.Permission = value;
            CallPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string AccessControllType
    {
        get => folder.AccessControllType;
        set
        {
            folder.AccessControllType = value;
            CallPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string IsInherited
    {
        get => folder.IsInherited;
        set
        {
            folder.IsInherited = value;
            CallPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int FolderId
    {
        get => folder.FolderId;
        set
        {
            folder.FolderId = value;
            CallPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

AView Model:

```
abstract class AViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void CallPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = null) 
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

I want to filter them that only a specific UserGroup is displayed in the view. How should I continue?

Comment: You could create a `FolderViewModel` class for a start?

Comment: I created that class with the Properties and edited the post. Do I need to change the DataContext to the `FolderVM` class?

Comment: You can use the `.Filter` property of your view component (whichever you are using) to display the collection filtered. It requires a predicate which optimally comes from your view model as well.

Comment: So i don't need to change anything with the binding? Shouldn't I bind to the VM class?

Comment: Just as note: CallPropertyChanged("Permission"); is bad - if you rename you may forget to change those. Make it a CallPropertyChanged() and then use a parmeter that is attributed for the compiler to autofill the property name (yes, those exist)